# Activation of Google Email Migration API

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-email-migration

My organization is in the process of switching to Google Apps for Education. I have successfully used Google Email Uploader to migrate my emails (as an admin of the domain). However, when I attempt to upload another users email, I encounter the following error:

```
Username or password not accepted

This domain does not allow users to access the Email Migration API.
Error 403
```

API Access has been enabled in the User Settings for our domain. Does this take some time to activate? Are there other steps I must take prior to migration? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Administrators of Google Apps for Business/EDU domains always have the ability to migrate mail. However in order for users to be able to migrate mail to their own account, it must be enabled in the Control Panel. See Google's instructions for [enabling user email migration](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2525613).